# Why did so many contractions fall out of use in Spanish?

Tags: historia, ortografía, preposiciones, contracciones

[Up until the 18th century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deste%2C+de+este&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3), written Spanish used many contractions of prepositions:

- de él > [dél](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=d%C3%A9l)
- de ello > [dello](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=dello)
- de algo > [dalgo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=dalgo)
- de ese > [dese](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=dese)
- de este > [deste](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=deste)
- de este otro > [destotro](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=destotro)
- de entrambos > [dentrambos](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=dentrambos)

- de [o](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qlr66uc) > [do](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=E1zbR6E)
- de [y](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c8IFPyp) > [dí](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=d%C3%AD)
- de acá > [dacá](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=dac%C3%A1)
- de allá > [dallá](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=dall%C3%A1)
- de hoy > [doy](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=doy)

- desde el > [desdel](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=desdel)
- ese otro > [esotro](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=esotro)
- nuestro amo > [nuestramo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=nuestramo)
- en la > enna > [na](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=na)

But the only ones that appear to have survived into modern use are *del* and *al*.<sup>1</sup>

Is there any reason the others fell out of use?

Comment: I'd like to point out that some of them are actually "used" in spoken language, but nobody would ever write them. We tend to rejoin them in casual speech, but we do know that they are written separately and it would be a shame if someone discovered we wrote them together haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that all of them —except for *na*— have in common is that in modern Spanish, the element after the preposition is tonic, that is, it has a stress.  In the case of *del* and *al*, there are two separate unstressed elements, one of which ends in a vowel and the second of which begins with one.  That heavily favors combining<sup>1</sup> as that happens naturally in spoken Spanish with unstressed vowels anyways (*tengo que escribir* will probably have a normal length /e/ for most speakers in normal speech, but *que eche algo* will more likely feature distinct vowels via lengthening and volume change because the second is stressed).

So when the changes started happening that favored distinct vowel sounds in most combinations, in the double unstressed vowel cases (which are basically just *del* and *al*, the distinction never occurred, and although today *a el* wouldn't end up *al* in speech (probably more likely /ajl/), it remained fossilized.

---

<sup>1. Based on some other peninsular languages, I wouldn't be surprised if the vowel in *el* was epinthetical for some period.  In Mirandese it's literally just *l* (*l gato* = *el gato*) and in Asturian and Aragonese around vowels the tendencies is to reduce it to *l’–* or *–’l* (*l’asturianu*, *l’aragonés*, *diome’l llibru*).</sup>

Comment: Note that when *de* is followed by *e-* there's no written contraction, but the vowels actually merge in speech unless the speaker makes an effort not to do so, so *deste*, *dese* y *desdel* do exist in speech.

Comment: @pablodf76 they probably fully merge in very fast speech, but at least for me, there is a clear rising volume (and for *dé el libro* a falling) that indicates the double vowel. YMMV though

Comment: To be clear, with *deste* and *dese* I'm talking about adjectival use (i.e. demonstrative followed by a noun: *deste hombre*, *desa calle*, etc.)